# @User.Identity.Name empty on mac

Tags: .net-core, windows-authentication

I used Windows authentication before and I really like it because the user has to do nothing and they're signed in. But now I'm developing using .Net **Core** and I'm on a mac. So I ran the following:

```
dotnet new webapp --auth Windows
```

I didn't change any code at all but I did install the dependencies. Then I ran the app and I see it says "Hello, !" Clearly `@User.Identity.Name` is empty. Is there something else I'm supposed to do?

I'm using: .NET Command Line Tools (2.2.300).

Comment: When creating the web app through the Visual Studio Community 2017 UI I was able to create a .Net Core 2.2 Asp.NET Core web app with working Windows Authentication. I selected File -> New -> Project -> ASP.NET Core Web Application -> Web Application. The only other thing to do was change the authentication type

Comment: @foochow thanks for the information. I made a .net core app from visual studio on my windows machine and enabled windows authentication for the app. I ran it and it worked. Then I opened the same project on my mac and the username was blank again. Seems like authentication doesn't work on mac.

Comment: You do understand that *Windows authentication* is for **Windows**, right? It's not *Apple authentication* or *Mac authentication*. *Windows authentication* is provided by the Windows operating system.

Comment: lol thanks @KenWhite. I just wanted confirmation before I go to my manager and tell him.

Comment: I think you should explore Single Sign On instead of Windows Authentication for Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Authentication on Mac and Linux will be supported once ASP.NET Core 3.0 is released. You can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel).

Of course, you can use the [preview release](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0) even now.